# How do you determine if a file is in a folder hierarchy

Tags: c#, directory

Is there a way to determine if a given file path is part of a certain folder hierarchy?

I have a folder path and I want to use it with an icon overlay. So I am going to be given a file path, and I need to determine whether it is in my folder hierarchy or not.

The best way I can see to do this, is to just check to see if the file path starts with the folder path.

```
if (!FolderPath.EndsWith("\\"))
    FolderPath = FolderPath + "\\";

if (FilePath.StartsWith(FolderPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

(One would have to enforce that the folder path ends with a backslash so that we don't match with files with added suffixes in the same directory as the folder.)

This will probably work, but is there a better way?

Comment: Looks like a pretty good solution to me.

Comment: for sugar just write return FilePath.StartsWith(FolderPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);